# PDO:: Confusion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have no idea why this is not returning anything. I'll show the code and talk through the steps I've taken.

```
if (isset($_GET['observation'])) {
    require_once("../func/connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM observations WHERE option = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $_GET['observation']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row['question'];

} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

`$row` dumps a false boolean, `$row['question']` is null.

I've wrote about a million queries and don't have a clue why this doesn't work.

Database table `observations` consists of `id`, `question` & `option` and the `bindValue` is correct to match a string in the database.

However, it returns null.

Comment: always add `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` and check out the error. `$row === false` means it failed

Comment: @Ghost `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option = 'obs_tld''` Thank you. However, the error doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: the correct answer is already below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`option` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql so you need to quote it with backticks:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM observations WHERE `option` = ?";
```

Comment: Ah, a backwards.. I always choose the best titles for my columns! thank you, I'll accept in5 mins